# Is it possible to query for 3 things at once?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a 5 star voting system to my new page. I have the following 4 tables : id, sid, rating, ipaddress.

What I'm trying to do (in my query) is calculate the average vote for a news entry, count how many total votes there are + check to see if the ip address has already voted on this news item.

This is what I have already to handle the vote average / vote count :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(rating) AS ave_rating, count(*) AS votes FROM news_ratings WHERE sid = $sid GROUP BY sid");
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$rating = $obj->ave_rating;
$votes = $obj->votes;
```

Can this be modified to also check the "ipaddress" table to see if there is a match?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php; it's strictly a question about the SQL involved. You might want to edit your question and remove the extraneous information that isn't related to the SQL itself; it will make it more clear, and therefore improve your chances of getting a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you have 4 *columns*, rather than tables...

You just need to add a logical `AND` to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(rating) AS ave_rating,
  count(*) AS votes 
FROM news_ratings
WHERE
  sid = $sid
  AND ipaddress = '$ipaddress'
GROUP BY sid
```

#### Update

After comments, to return an IP match with the same query, you can use a `CASE` statement to create a column called `ipmatch` in your `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(rating) AS ave_rating,
  count(*) AS votes, 
  CASE WHEN ipaddress = '$ipaddress' THEN 'IP-MATCH' ELSE 'IP-NOMATCH' END AS ipmatch
FROM news_ratings
WHERE
  sid = $sid
GROUP BY sid
```

Comment: Sorry, I did mean columns. The problem with your example is that - if there is no ip address match, it returns 0 rows. I would still like to have the average rating / vote counts information. I was hoping I could still grab that information + do a ip address check all in one query .. maybe it's not possible?

Comment: @Dave Great, happy to help. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark if you're satisfied, and welcome to Stack Overflow.